# `$('#form').serialize()` messes up UTF-8 characters

Tags: javascript, encoding

I'm inserting a form with AJAX and I'm using: `$('#form').serialize()` to get all the input and send it to insert.php.

The problem is that characters like `á` become `%A9` and such.

How can I prevent this from happening before sending it or how get the correct characters when I retrieve it through $_POST so I can insert them correctly to my database?

EDIT -----

Btw: Same Form with no AJAX, just action="POST" to the SAME insert.php inserts correctly, so the problem is solely with serialize() messing the HTML.

Comment: no, I'm reading about it right now. I don't really know how to apply it, btw I can insert things easily to the database. The only problem seems to be when I use the function .serialize() but I don't really have any other way to insert to the DB unless I stop using AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery `serialize()` serializes as UTF-8.  So `á` becomes the correct UTF-8 encoding `%c3%a1`.    Try using the `$_REQUEST` as that is already decoded as per the php documentation. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: `urldecode($_POST['data'])` before inserting into database solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

The final step you need to do is to decode in your PHP file like this:

$usuario=utf8_decode($_POST['nombre']);

I use to combine utf8_decode() with htmlspecialchars() before sending datas to the database:

$nombres = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombres']));