# Codeigniter Ajax (JQuery serialize) and UTF-8 characters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

Please note that this is a JQuery-Ajax-CodeIgniter issue.

All files involved in the post process are UTF8 encoded.
At non-Ajax calls, all of my forms work perfectly with UTF8 characters.
At Ajax calls, the Firebug/Chrome sniffers display the posted values correctly.

If I print the $_POST array in the index.php (root file), the values appear correctly.

CI is doing something that is placing question marks where the curly quotes are and trimming the strings at the first accented character.

From the sound of it, iconv could be messing with the strings, so I tried removing XSS, commenting the iconv and mb_convert_encoding lines from CI system/core/Input.php and system/core/Utf8.php, but no joy.

After suffering a bit I decided to have a look at the $_REQUEST. OMG, the strings are correctly displayed there, so instead of $_POST I use $_REQUEST (not that I like it).

I found the following post saying that we should use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST:
[`$('#form').serialize()` messes up UTF-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496540/form-serialize-messes-up-utf-8-characters), which then points back to the PHP [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function.

I am not sure the problem is related to the urldecode as the $_POST array changes after being treated by CI.

So, should I keep using $_REQUEST in my Ajax controllers or is there a better solution for this problem?

Any thoughts in the security/XSS side?

Thanks!

Comment: instead of `serialize` why not go with `json_encode()` ? Should be cleaner to handle. Just an alternate way of thinking

Comment: @Jakub what do you mean, json_encode in JQuery?