# jQuery post serialize russian

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, cyrillic

I am trying to post data to a database and the campaigns run in 6 languages, 1 being Russian and its unable to handle the Cyrillic text.

The DTB is setup for UTF8 as the last campaign also used Russian, but jQUery with that one.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#form").submit(function ()
    { //Use forms ID
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/postData.php",
            data: str,
            success: function (msg)
            {
                if (msg == 'OK')
                {
                    //alert('success');
                    $('#thankYou').delay(100).fadeIn(350);
                } else
                {
                    result = msg;
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The error I am getting is "Incorrect string value: '\xC3\x91\xC2\x80\xC3\x91...'"

Tried editing the post data with

```
$country = utf8_decode($_POST['country']);
```

Which posts, but then its all ?'s in the DTB.

How would I get jQuery to correctly handle this post fur Russian. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496540/form-serialize-messes-up-utf-8-characters

Comment: Try looking your javascript file's encoding. I think it should be in UTF8 too

Comment: I dont think you need to call utf8_decode at all.

Comment: all the files are UTF8, double checked.

Comment: Where is the error coming from? If it is MySQL - check the encoding of your db connection. Also check if PHP is receiving the right text in UTF-8.

Comment: Its a mysql error, the jquery is passing %D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9 for country instead of русский.

Its problematic before it gets to the post data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial, error, another forum and plenty of google I found a solution.
Wrap a decodeURI around the str variable.

```
        var str1 = $(this).serialize();
        var str = decodeURI(str1);
```

That fixes up the URI string that jQuery parses on to the post data