# How to use to decode data sent using AJAX in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, sinatra

I am very confused. I am sending my data using ajax after the information is introduced in one textarea. However, the info. is corrupted in this way: When writing `pasá` it would received in the server as `pas%C3%A1`

I already checked that `pas%C3%A1` corresponds to UTF-8. [URLEncode Code Chart](http://www.backbone.se/urlencodingUTF8.htm)

I also checked this link:
[`$('#form').serialize()` messes up UTF-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496540/form-serialize-messes-up-utf-8-characters)

but without success. This is for PHP.

**Question:** How can I decode UTF-8 in Ruby? or how can I avoid this corrupted data

I have defined this in my view:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /
```

To get the info. from my view and to send it to the server I use:

```
$('textarea').change(function(e){
            var pointer = $(this);
            //Compare colors when focus is lost, if orange==orange, then send data
            var color = pointer.css("background-color");
            if (color == 'rgb(250, 187, 0)'){
                var id = pointer.attr("id");
                var getNumberFromId = id.substr(2,3);
                var getLanguage = id.substr(0,2);
                var getKey = $("#key"+getNumberFromId).html();
                var getKey = getKey.replace(" ","");
                console.log(getKey);

                e.stopPropagation();
                pointer.css('background-color','#8Fbc8F'); // Change field to green
                toServer(pointer,getKey, getLanguage);              
            }           
          });

            function toServer(pointer, key, language) {         
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/translator/translate/'+language+'/'+key,
                    data: {data:pointer.serialize()},               
                    success: function(data){

                    }
                }); 
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly then you are trying to decode it at the server side. If that is the case then you could try something like this:

```
require 'cgi'
s = "pas%C3%A1"
string = CGI::unescape(s)
puts string # pasá
```